# Is there an option to zero-pad line numbers?

Tags: line-numbers

When using `set number` and `set numberwidth` I'd like to have the line numbers padded with zeros instead of spaces.

example:

```
0001
0002
0003
```

Can it be done?

Comment: Not unless you change Vim's source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, this can only be done by changing the Vim source code and rebuilding.

The changes you need to make are as follows:

For zero-padded `number`, in [`src/screen.c`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/b8d4905592fc26fcd09180d7d6bfefd899f2f6c6/src/screen.c) on lines **[2502](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/b8d4905592fc26fcd09180d7d6bfefd899f2f6c6/src/screen.c#L2502)** and **[3712](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/b8d4905592fc26fcd09180d7d6bfefd899f2f6c6/src/screen.c#L3712)**, replace:

```c
char *fmt = "%*ld ";
```

with

```c
char *fmt = "%0*ld ";
```

For zero-padded `relativenumber`, in the same file, on lines **[2519](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/b8d4905592fc26fcd09180d7d6bfefd899f2f6c6/src/screen.c#L2519)** and **[3725](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/b8d4905592fc26fcd09180d7d6bfefd899f2f6c6/src/screen.c#L3725)**, replace:

```c
fmt = "%-*ld ";
```

with

```c
fmt = "%0*ld ";
```

Line numbers noted above are for the current version on Github, 7.4.1799.

Comment: From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31282559/1121933): *Be sure to use the [canonical URL](https://help.github.com/articles/getting-permanent-links-to-files/). You can get it for a particular commit by pressing the `y` key. The URL in your browser will change accordingly.*

Comment: @JairLopez Cool, I didn't know about that feature on github.  I updated the URLs in my answer.